# Specifying generic enum type as type when extending abstract class

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have the following situation

```
public interface MyCriteria<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    public T getValue();

}

public abstract class AbstractMyCriteria<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MyCriteria<T>{
    private String code;

    public AbtsractMyCriteria(String code){
        this.code=code;
    }
}
```

I have a number of classes such as the following for different types (Date, String, Integer etc.)

```
public DateEqualsMyCriteria extends AbstractMyCriteria<Date>{
    private Date value;

    public DateEqualsMyCriteria(String code,Date value){
        super(code);
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

I need to write another class that can handle Enumerations as the type instead of Date, Integer, String etc., but everything I try leads to compilation errors.

For example say I have the following enumerations

```
public enum Type {
    Attribute,
    Entity
}

public enum Operation {
    Equal,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqualTo,
    NotNull,
    Null,
    Wildcard
}
```

I need to be able to something such as

```
EnumEqualsMyCriteria enumEqualsMyCriteria=new EnumEqualsMyCriteria("Name",Type.Entity);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE*

What I have tried is

```
public class AttributeEnumEqualsFlexxCriteria extends AbstractFlexxCriteria<Enum> implements Comparable<Enum>
```

but that gives the error java.land.Enum is not within it's bounds must implement Comparable even though I have implemented compareTo within the class.

Comment: All enums are subclasses of Enum, so you can take Enum as a type parameter. Does that help?

Comment: Hi JP I tried that but got an Enum not bound error and am not sure how to get around that. Thanks

Comment: Also, you concrete class does nothing your abstract class can't do. You can have a value of class T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles and does what you want, I think:

```
public class EnumEqualsMyCriteria<T extends Enum<T>> extends AbstractMyCriteria<T>{
private T value;



public EnumEqualsMyCriteria(String code,T value) {
    super(code);
    this.value=value;
}


@Override
public T getValue() {
    return value; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumEqualsMyCriteria<Type> ec=new EnumEqualsMyCriteria<Type>("Name", Type.Entity);
}
}
```

You can of course have a specific class for the Type enum, if you wish.